# Nested for loop to perform calculation on excel rows

Tags: python, excel, for-loop

I've currently created the below code to go into an excel sheet and create two new columns based on two columns in the excel sheet and two variables within my code.

Now i want to be able loop through a list of tuples with those two variables in and create multiple new columns in the excel sheet. So waypointLat & waypointLon will be in a lsit of tuples like ((51.454, -2.123), (51.555,-2.377), .....)

I have two questions really
1/ Is this the best way to approach it? Should I load the data as a dataframe instead?
2/ If it is feasible to do within the excel file, how do i iterate through columns?

Thanks,

```
waypointLat = '51.364718'
waypointLong = '-0.2507693'

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'Desktop\Python Projects\Work - Transport Movement\CurrentYodelTransportLocations.xlsx')
ws1 = wb.active

last_row = 2200  # Enter last row of excel workbook here


for i in range(2, last_row):
    cell = "V" + str(i)
    cell2 = "W" + str(i)
    latitude = "N" + str(i)
    longitude = "O" + str(i)
    ws1[cell] = '=(((ACOS(SIN((' + latitude + '*PI()/180)) * SIN((' + waypointLat + '*PI()/180))+COS((' + latitude + '*PI()/180)) * COS((' + waypointLat + '*PI()/180)) * COS(((' + longitude + ' - ' + waypointLong + ')*PI()/180))))*180/PI())*60*1.1515*1.609344)'
    ws1[cell2] = '=IF(' + cell +'<=8,"Yes","No")'
wb.save(r'Desktop\Python Projects\Work - Transport Movement\CurrentYodelTransportLocationsAmended.xlsx')
```

Comment: I would recommend loading the file into a dataframe, performing operations on it and then saving it as excel again.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, openpyxl allows some ways looping over columns, e.g. below code:

```
for col in ws1.iter_cols(min_row=2, max_row=last_row, min_col=14, max_col=17):
    for cell in col:
        print(cell.value) # Otherwise you can set value
```

However, for your purpose I guess we should loop through rows in order to process data row by row instead:

```
for row in ws1.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=last_row, min_col=14, max_col=17):
    for cell in row:
        # manipulating data here
```